# Python сложение элементов попарно из разных массивов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

я понимаю, что python ошибиться не может, но какаято абсурдная арифметика получается, посмотрите плз. Я получил два массива `m_` и `m__`. Теперь я хочу попарно их сложить элементы и получить новый список.

Вот сюда я загрузил исходный файл с данными https://yadi.sk/d/hVZw12w-gI38iA

На выходе я хочу получить массив `sum_m`, который попарно суммирует значения элементов из массивов `m_` и `m__`.

Вот код

```
import pandas as pd
import collections

""" Чтение файла """

file = r"C:\si2.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";")

""" Добавление нового столбца в датафрейм (разница) """

df["<DELTA>"] = df["<CLOSE>"] - df["<OPEN>"]
print(df.head(5))

massiv = []
for i in df["<DELTA>"]:
    massiv.append(i)

print(massiv)
print(len(massiv))
print("----------------------------------------")

""" Создание массивов в помощь для поиска индексов смены свечей """

m_ = []
m__ = []

for i in massiv:
    if i >= 0:
        m_.append(1)
    else:
        m_.append(-1)

print(" Первый массив", m_)
print(len(m_))

m__ = m_
m__.insert(0, 0)
m__ = m__[0: len(massiv)]

print(" Второй массив", m__)
print(len(m__))
print("----------------------------------------")

""" Поиск индексов смены свечей """

sum_m = [m_ + m__ for m_, m__ in zip(m_, m__)]
print(sum_m)
print(len(sum_m))
```

Вот, что получается на выходе, какая то непонятная арифметика.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тут наглядно покажу ,что хочу от алгоритма на первых 4-ех элементах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется ответ лежит гдето на поверхности, но я его упорно не вижу.

Comment: что если вот так ```sum_m=[]
for m_, m__ in zip(m_, m__):sum_m.append(m_+m__)
```

Comment: тоже самое получается

Comment: Поменяйте имена переменных которые бегают в цикле последнем. Не надо называть их также как и массивы

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU Данные добавил и вроде подкоректировал вопрос.

Comment: @Nobody чесно сказать не очень понял, что надо сделать

Comment: “На выходе я хочу получить массив sum_m, как указанно в коде ниже” - непонятно что вы хотите получить на выходе. Можете привести в вопросе пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Я хочу получить массив sum_m, в котором бы sum_m[0] = m_[0] + m__[0], sum_m[1] = m_[1] + m__[1] и т.д. Попарно бы складывались значения.

Comment: Для того, чтобы понять что вы хотите получить на выходе нам следует понять как должен работать ваш нерабочий код? Это немного неэффективно. Предлагаю вам вместо этого привести в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Это поможет понять ваши намерения

Comment: @MaxU Вроде поправил в самом вопросе)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

df["m_"] = np.where(df["<DELTA>"] >= 0, 1, -1)
df["m__"] = df["m_"].shift().fillna(0)
res = df.eval("res = m_ + m__")
```

---

результат:

```
In [13]: res
Out[13]:
      <OPEN>  <HIGH>  <LOW>  <CLOSE>  <DELTA>  m_  m__  res
0      64950   65000  64831    64898      -52  -1  0.0 -1.0
1      64881   64898  64836    64870      -11  -1 -1.0 -2.0
2      64872   64872  64758    64788      -84  -1 -1.0 -2.0
3      64786   64835  64773    64830       44   1 -1.0  0.0
4      64840   64915  64798    64899       59   1  1.0  2.0
...      ...     ...    ...      ...      ...  ..  ...  ...
4082   71060   71130  71028    71088       28   1 -1.0  0.0
4083   71086   71148  71014    71039      -47  -1  1.0  0.0
4084   71039   71061  70879    70909     -130  -1 -1.0 -2.0
4085   70907   71064  70905    71014      107   1 -1.0  0.0
4086   71013   71104  70976    71097       84   1  1.0  2.0

[4087 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, всеголишь 4 строчки))) вместо моего сочинения)

Comment: @КириллМаликов, решение заняло у меня 2-3 минуты, а вот попытки понять что  же вы пытаетесь сделать отняли гораздо больше времени. На будущее советую всегда приводить в вопросе небольшие примеры (5-7 строк) входных данных и обязательно то, что вы хотите получить на выходе из указанных входных данных. Это сэкономит и ваше и наше время ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и совет)

Answer (score 1):

m__ = m_     ошибка в этой строчке

m__ не стал присваивать массив m_, а просто заново прогнал через for и все получилось